# Javascript .charAt(0) gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript

```
var category = "a()";

if(category.charAt(0) == /^[a-zA-Z]+$/){


    /*This part doesn't gets executed*/
    /*What is the problem with the if condition?*/


}
```

Comment: you are equating a character to a regex expression... not running the regex

Comment: You cannot use the `==` operator with a regular expression. Likely Javascript is treating it like a string.

Comment: Thanks. Got a clear understanding now.

Answer (score 9):

You are comparing your character with an instance of a regular expression.
You actually want to test your character with the regular expression.

You can do that like this:

```
var category = "a()";

if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(category.charAt(0))) {
    // Now it will get executed
}
```

Further reading on JavaScript regex flavor:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: And since the string will always only be one character, the expression can be simplified to `[a-zA-Z]`, or `/[a-z]/i`.